# A different kind of damped harmonic motion

Tags: energy, oscillators

I've read about damped harmonic motion in Feynman's lectures Volume 1. The characteristic was that the damping force was directly proportional to velocity. Is there  a kind of damped motion in which the damping force is directly proportional to displacement instead? How would such a system be constructed (if that's engineering, ignore it), and what kinds of equations would apply?

To clarify, the way in which this hypothetical damping system works is it focuses on absorbing potential energy, i.e. it decreases the height of the pendulum. Conventional damping decreases kinetic energy.

Comment: The $-kv$ damping is taught because (a) it is a reasonable approximation to the behavior of a reasonable fraction of real mechanical systems, (b) it is mathematically tractable, and (c) it is almost exactly realized in electrical oscillators and in many optical materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, although the reasoning behind it is more straightforward than you think.

You are correct that there is a direct relationship between force and velocity.  It is also true that there is a direct relation between force and displacement.  This is because there is a direct relation between velocity and displacement.

The overall tone of your question seems to suggest that you believe there is some different kind of damped motion out there where force is proportional to distance.  Such motion exists, but it is the exact same stuff, just solved for a different variable.

Comment: Do you have any websites about solving those equations for different variable?